# How to add own OMX_decoder in Android?

Tags: android

I want to add my own `OMX_Decoder` to `android`, I want to understand that, how much important it is to understand Opencore and Stagefright for same.

Say, I go ahead with Android 2.1 which has opencore,what will be the rework I need to do for **Android 2.3** or further android versions.

Please help me, how to move ahead what will be the best choice, what will be the steps to add OMX_Decoder in both cases?

Please do the needful.

Thank You!

Deepak C.

Answer (score 0):

A good understanding of Stagefright framework and opencore is needed to accommodate your own OMX wrapped decoder. In stagefright  framework, it will not be that difficult if you are taking the frames back from the decoder rather than OMX decoder component pushing the data to the renderer. You need to refer OMXCodec.cpp and few other OMX files and AwesomePlayer.cpp files. Also, now Opencore is obsolete, so I don't see any point in adding a decoder in opencore framework.

Vibgyor